# Why didn't Kreacher disapparate with Regulus from the cave?

Tags: harry-potter

When Kreacher tells his story in the Deathly Hallows he says Regulus ordered him to leave him behind and disapparate himself. But why wouldn't Regulus save himself? We know that house elves can side apparate with people like Dobby did a little later in Deathly Hallows.

So why wouldn't Regulus ask Kreacher to take them both back after they had switched the lockets? Or why didn't he bring water with him since Kreacher had told him what happens when you drink from the lake? He could have saved himself and destroyed the locket and Voldemort wouldn't know until he checked again which evidently didn't happen for many years. (I'm not exactly sure what year Regulus died but his mother was still alive).

Comment: Hindsight and/or idiot ball plot reasons.

Comment: Is this *in* the movie, BTW? I thought they cut Kreacher's tale out.

Comment: @Walt hes in the movies http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Kreacher and Ive added the youtube scene where its explained.

Comment: @cde The scene you just linked does not contain Kreacher's story at all. The *character* is there, yes, but not the story the question is about. In fact, I'm almost positive Kreacher's tale about the cave was cut out of the movie and this is really a question about the *book*.

Comment: I know that the question has not been properly answered on scifi.se also because it has a really vague answer, it could be anything

Comment: @walt that doesn't mean the events arnt canon in the movie. Many things were skipped but referenced instead. I think this falls under that.

Comment: @cde Huh? If this is referenced anywhere in the movies, I'll shut up. But if it's not (and I'm pretty sure it wasn't), *it never existed in them*. How can it be canon? Or on-topic on Movies&TV?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20832/regulus-black-and-the-horcrux-cave ? (the question is very similar, but there was no real answer to this point...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### He ordered Kreacher to leave without him

> “And he order—Kreacher to leave—without him. And he told Kreacher—to
> go home—and never to tell my Mistress—what he had done—but to destroy—
> the first locket. And he drank—all the potion—and Kreacher swapped the
> lockets—and watched . . . as Master Regulus . . . was dragged beneath
> the water . . . and . . . “
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Kreacher, of course, as a house-elf enslaved to the Black family, was bound to obey. Of course, he could have disobeyed his orders on pain of being compelled to punish himself in the future, but he seemed to have a great deal of respect for Regulus, and therefore would not likely have disobeyed.

As to why he *specifically*  asked Kreacher to leave without him, we can only guess. The fact that he ordered Kreacher to leave without him suggests that he considered the possibility that Kreacher could leave with him. I can think of two possibilities:

1. The potion would have eventually killed him. The potion may not have been immediately lethal, but it is possible that without drinking water immediately, the potion would be fatal. It seems unlikely he would have known this, though. If anything, Kreacher's example would suggest to him that the potion wasn't lethal.
2. Perhaps he felt certain that Voldemort would hunt him down and kill him. He could never return to the Death Eaters, for fear that Voldemort would use Legilimancy to see what was in his mind. If he defected, Voldemort would kill him quickly anyway. Perhaps he preferred an immediate death to being hunted down by Voldemort.

Ultimately, neither of these explanations is entirely satisfactory. The second makes more sense, but requires Regulus to be fairly resigned or suicidal.

---

As  an answer to your second question:

### Bringing water probably wouldn't have worked

Harry tried to conjure water after Dumbledore drank the potion, but he failed:

> Aguamenti!” he shouted, jabbing the goblet with his wand. The goblet
> filled with clear water; Harry dropped to his knees beside Dumbledore,
> raised his head, and brought the glass to his lips — but it was empty.
> Dumbledore groaned and began to pant.
>
> “But I had some — wait —
> Aguamenti!” said Harry again, pointing his wand at the goblet. Once
> more, for a second, clear water gleamed within it, but as he
> approached Dumbledore’s mouth, the water vanished again.
>
> “Sir, I’m
> trying, I’m trying!” said Harry desperately, but he did not think that
> Dumbledore could hear him; he had rolled onto his side and was drawing
> great, rattling breaths that sounded agonizing. “Aguamenti — Aguamenti
> — AGUAMENTI!”
>
> The goblet filled and emptied once more. And now
> Dumbledore’s breathing was fading. His brain whirling in panic, Harry
> knew, instinctively, t**he only way left to get water, because Voldemort
> had planned it so...**
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

Clearly Voldemort had made plans, in order to leave a potential intruder with no other option than to drink from the lake and be dragged down by the Inferi. Presumably this would have extended to more mundane attempts to bring water into the cave, or to drink water therein.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second explanation makes the most sense I think if Regulus wasn't a good occlumens and he believed Voldemort would know his secret. Of course him dying in the cave would probably have Voldemort wondering what happened to him. If Voldemort didn't care about Regulus' disappearance it means that he didn't have to die and he could have gone to hiding.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the most likely explanation is that Regulus knew he could never escape Voldemort if he got out of the cave and ran for it (it says a couple times in the books that it's impossible to run away from Voldemort, look at Karakroff). He knew that if Voldemort caught up with him, he would for sure find out what Regulus did, either using torture or Legilimancy. For that same reason, Regulus couldn't go back to Voldemort and pretend nothing happenned, and we know that Death Eater can't just quit: they serve Voldemort or die. So basically, Regulus knew he had to die if they were to stand a chance of destroying the horcrux and rendering Voldemort mortal once more. There was no way around it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, take a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). Could you provide any canonical sources to aid you answer? You mention that one of your comments comes is said a few times in the books, could you provide the sources for them just to make your answer a little stronger! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The water would have disappeared or prevented them from entering the cave. There is no way Voldemort never thought of that. Regalia didn't know how to defeat the inferi so he knew he would have to let them kill him in order to procure the locket.